# Utiliser le verbe « mener » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes

J'ai une question sur l'utilisation du verbe « mener ». Est-ce :

> La croissance économique en 1970 **a mené à faire** baisser de taux de
>   chômage.

ou

> La croissance économique en 1970 **a mené à** baisser de taux de
>   chômage.

Laquelle est la bonne ? Et comment dois-je l'utiliser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*mené à faire baisser* est plus naturel.

Ceci dit, ça n'est pas du français très actuel (peut être une traduction trop littérale de l'anglais *to lead* ou *to conduct*).

La même phrase avec *conduit à* ou *entraîné* serait plus naturelle.

Quant aux usages communs du verbe *mener*, ce seraient plutôt aujourd'hui des utilisations au sens propre du verbe :

- il nous a mené tout droit à la défaite
- il est un vrai meneur d'hommes
- l'équipe X mène à la mi-temps du match

Answer (score 4):

Le plus naturel dans cette phrase c'est d'utiliser un substantif, autrement il y a un doute sur le sujet de l’action qui n'est pas mentionné dans la proposition principale.

> La croissance économique en 1970 a mené à la baisse du taux de chômage.

Lorsqu'un sujet apparaît, il n'y a pas de tel problème. La phrase suivante est tout à fait naturelle :

> Les récents chamboulements ont mené Pierre à changer de stratégie.